# Search and Split the found Text

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to find a place from the input text and set the number after the = as a variable. Unfortunately, what is wrong output

With my code, the maxresults variable returns "i" as the result. But it should be 20.

Code:

```
bind pub "-|-" !a pub:a
proc pub:a { nick host handle channel text } {

    set maxresults ""
    if {[regexp -nocase {max=} $text]} {
    set maxresults0 [lindex [split $text max=] 1]
    set maxresults [lindex $maxresults0 0]
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :maxresults: $maxresults"
    }
}
```

Input:
!a Remix find now country=german max=20 currency=euro

Output:
maxresults: i

but it should be:
maxresults: 20

Comment: The problem with that split command is that it takes the 2nd argument ("max=") as a **set of characters** to split on, not one single string. https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/split.htm

Comment: Either `regsub -all`/`string map` substitute in a character unlikely to appear in the text (e.g., an unallocated Unicode codepoint from the private use area) or use an RE to select the characters you want  in a `regexp -all -inline`. Which is best... depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the whole job with `regexp` -

```
if {[regexp -nocase {max=(\d+)} $text - maxresults]} {
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :maxresults: $maxresults"
}
```

See the documentation at http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm